# When I use unicurses, there comes: NameError: name 'initscr' is not defined

Tags: python, import, nameerror, unicurses

I downloaded and installed unicurses and when I write into python idle "import unicurses", it works without error.
Then I write:

```
stdscr = initscr()
```

And then a name error occurs:

```
NameError: name 'initscr' is not defined
```

Everywhere I look in the internet for an unicurses tutorial, there is always explained that one has to start with "stdscr = initscr()", and there is no implication that it won't work when "import unicurses" had no problem.

For example here: https://medium.com/@vworri/terminal-based-ui-python-unicurses-561f94d8250c

Or here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4s_wHUNCHK0&list=PL1H1sBF1VAKXLJ3cHisqjy4nGYDMqYIzo&index=2

What am I doing wrong, so that this NameError occurs?

Thank you very much
Greetings
cs_question_asker

Comment: That article is over 4 years old and that video is over 8 years old. Could very well be outdated information. Unicurses seems pretty old, you might just try using `curses` which is now officially included with Python.

Comment: try something like [`python3.9 -m pip install uni-curses`](https://github.com/unicurses/unicurses)